# Deployed rails app using chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there is any predefined cookbook to deployed rails app using chef.

I have searched a lot and found a resources:
http://www.concreteinteractive.com/how-to-deploy-a-rails-application-anywhere-with-chef/

Is there any good stuff from it or alternatives? Please share your experiences.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. The Opscode cookbook page has tons of resources

http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/rails_application

Answer (score 0):

Chef [wiki](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Build+A+Rails+Stack) have lot of resources. You can check there. Try this one https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Build+A+Rails+Stack

Answer (score 0):

You can download cookbook from [Opscode community sites](http://community.opscode.com/). You will get a search and Advance Search option on of basis of category and tags. Make sure to check out rating ,no of download, last update and followers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to deploy rails app server, http://devbox.co/setup-ruby-on-rails-server-quickly/ and then can use capistrano to deploy the code. There are multiple options like you want passenger or unicorn, mysql or posgresql etc. You can use any combination as both have predefined setup in separate branches.